# How can i add onChange on DateInput component

Tags: admin-on-rest

i'm new with admin-on-rest.
I want to add onChange event on

```
<DateInput source="day_date" />
```

how can i do that?
i tried

```
<DateInput source="day_date" onChange={(v) => {console.log(v)}}/>
```

and it seems not working.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateInput base on http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker .
it seems onChange take 2 params first of them always null(undefined).
but you can search source code of this component in your project `node_modules/admin-on-rest/src/mui/input/DateInput.js`
you need get 2 parameter for Date.
so just try this:

```
<DateInput source="start_date" onChange={(v, d) => {console.log(v, d)}}/>
```

in my browser I can see:

```
Object {preventDefault: function} Thu May 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (MSK)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the inputs behaviors, you'll have to write your own: [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component)